# query firestore with timestamp condition

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore document has a field: timestamp: "April 4, 2022 at 10:17:30 PM UTC+2"
My djangomodel has field: timestamp, when i print it it gives me "2022-04-04 22:19:19.514590+00:00"

I want to retrieve firestore data if timestamp firestore object > djangoObject_timestamp

The query to firestore:

```
query = query.where(u'timestamp', u'>',timestamp_from_saved_object)
```

However i get al the data from firestore, so it seems like the query is not working.
I am doubting the query code and the date formats, is it right ?

Comment: How is `timestamp_from_saved_object` initialized? It might be good to read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (again), as having a minimal repro makes it most likely that someone here can help.

Comment: As per @FrankvanPuffelen ,  It could be in the date format of your `timestamp_from_saved_object`. For debugging, could you please make the timestamp a string and convert it to proper timestamp format. See this code: ```date_time_str = '2022-04-04 22:19:19.514590+00:00'

timestamp_from_saved_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')``` and try to execute the query. If the code was able to get what you want to achieve then you should format your `timestamp_from_saved_object` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the datetime field in django which i use for the query to firestore. It was 2 hours ahead!. So the query contained the datetime + 2 hours. Thats why i got back the wrong date from firestore.

Solved it with a timedelta

```
timestamp_from_saved_object = timestamp_from_saved_object - timedelta(hours=2)
```

The query date is now the right time and i get back the right data from firestore.

Comment: Hi @saro could you please accept your posted answer so that it can also help the community.

Answer (score -1):

u try in a SQL format with mysql-connector???

```js
query = "SELECT timestamp FROM database WHERE timestamp > "+timestamp_from_saved_object
cursor.execute(query)
```

the format of dates... whats its your timestamp??
another timestamp of example from your database?

Comment: sorry man you lost me, i want to compare a time stamp from django model with a timestamp field from firestore.

Comment: sorry, but whate format have you in your dates? 

sometimes the timestamps do not match in formats. It has happened to me to have timestamp of more than 10 digits that have given me an error and I have had to convert... if it helps you

Comment: @virollo Firestore is a NoSQL database. Its query API is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry I don't use Firestore, but this isn't a problem with the database, it's a formatting problem.

I agree with @marc-anthony-b. you need to convert the format of the dates.